# How to find consecutive things in nested expressions?

Tags: pattern-matching

To find things that are consecutive you can use `SequenceCases`:

```
SequenceCases[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
       {x_, y_} /; (OddQ[x] && EvenQ[y]) :> {x, y}, \[Infinity]]
(*returns {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}*)
```

But this only works on lists, not for nested things:

```
nb = Notebook[{CellGroupData[{Cell["0", "Title"], 
  Cell["1", "Section"], Cell["2", "Text"]}], 
CellGroupData[{Cell["3", "Section"], Cell["4", "Text"]}]}];

SequenceCases[nb, {Cell[a_, "Section"], Cell[b_, "Text"]} :> {a, 
   b}, \[Infinity]]
(* I'm trying to get {{1,2},{3,4}}*)
```

What's would be an efficient way to do this for large notebooks, should I switch to `Cases`, or use `PatternSequence`?

Comment: @CarlWoll My mistake, just updated. When it's more nested I can't just use `SequenceCases` but then I can't get `Cases` to work either...

Comment: I see now what you're doing.  Perhaps you can use `Cases` for its *levelspec* like this: `Cases[nb, row_List :> 
  SequenceCases[row, {Cell[a_, "Section"], Cell[b_, "Text"]} :> {a, b}], {1, -1}]`